# Opengraph debugger giving error "there was an error following the redirect path." and "URL returned a bad HTTP response code."

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I run my page through the [Facebook Object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dangoodspeed.com%2Fshared%2Ff%2FDanDonovansThrow.mp4), it returns the messages:

Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Could Not Follow Redirect Path -    Using data from http://www.dangoodspeed.com/shared/f/DanDonovansThrow.mp4 because there was an error following the redirect path.

and

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Bad Response Code - URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

I'm at a loss as to how to fix them.  I get a successful 200 response code when I access the page.  And I don't know what "redirect path" it's talking about.

And in a tangent… does anyone know if there's a way to have it call photos and videos as such?  A friend liked the video and it came up as "liked an article" even though it's a video.  Changing the object type to "video.other" (which seems odd in itself) brought on other issues so I ended up changing it back to article.  And there's no "photo" object type that I could find.

Comment: Pay attention to the request headers, particularly the mime type, which for the Facebook debug tool is:

    */*

 ... something about that request differs from the ones from your browser. You can use the OG debug tool to send the request and then investigate it with a debugger or similar. Use SSH remote port forwarding to get the OG debug tool's request to go to your local machine and then you can pick it apart and see why your webserver responds differently (or throws an exception)

Comment: request mime type is asterisk-slash-asterisk ... I can't make the SO comment box leave my text alone...